# GCC including header files in windows

Tags: c, gcc, header

I have my project in a directory called junkyard. Inside junkyard, I have `test.c`, and a folder called include.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
}
```

And the two header files are located inside the include folder (which, again, is in the root directory of the project. So the structure's necessary files are located like this:

> junkyard/test.c
>
> junkyard/include/mysql.h
>
> junkyard/include/my_global.h

Note that I am using GCC on Windows. I am unable to compile the program, and I have tried several approaches. How do I link the header files correctly? Thanks.

Comment: You don't link the header files, linkage is 4 compilation stages later. However, adding `-Iinclude` to the compiler flags may solve this.

Comment: @H2CO3 So how do I include them when compiling `test.c`?

Comment: Could you show the exact compiler line?

Comment: @Zeta `gcc -I/include test.c` That's one of the ones I tried.

Comment: @capcom And that's bad. You don't need the slash. Only `gcc -Iinclude test.c`

Comment: @SparKot I didn't get that one.

Comment: @Zeta Perfect, thanks. I'm still a little new to this. In which case do I use `-I/pathname`?

Comment: @capcom if you're looking for an absolute path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all difference between [`#include` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename):

- `#include <>` means to include file from "compiler directory" (which can be set by [preprocessor option `-I`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options))
- `#include ""` means to include file from "local directory"

If you want to include file from your project you probably should use:

```c
#include "include/mysql.h"
#include "include/my_global.h"
```

If you (for some reasons) want to still use `#include <>` use gcc like this:

```
gcc -Iinclude test.c
```

Comment: Would `-Iinclude` be `-Iheaders` if, say, the headers were located in a folder called headers instead of include?

Comment: @capcom yes they would, I've added a link which describes it in gcc "Manual"